# Grabbing specific parts of string

Tags: php

I have a table containing user access filters. These filters contain a certain MySQL range that the user can search the data within, for instance:

```
start_time >= '2021-07-29 12:00' AND end_time <= '2021-07-30 12:00' AND customer_id = '12' AND wipe_status = 'SUCCESS'
```

All of this is stored within one string. I am looking to seperate the string so that I will get the following in this case:

```
$end_time = end_time <= '2021-07-30 12:00'
$customer_id = customer_id = '12'
$wipe_status = wipe_status = 'SUCCESS'
```

Trouble is the length of these can be variable so I am not sure how to use substring to seperate these. At times the filters will include and "OR" as well so I can't simply seperate by AND. Do you have any ideas as to how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer creating a dictionary whose keys correspond to the columns in the `WHERE` clause.  We can do a regex split on `AND` or `OR`, and then iterate the terms to populate the dictionary.

```php
$input = "start_time >= '2021-07-29 12:00' AND end_time <= '2021-07-30 12:00' AND customer_id = '12' AND wipe_status = 'SUCCESS'";
$parts = preg_split("/\s+(?:AND|OR)\s+/", $input);
$vals = array();
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $vals[explode(" ", $part)[0]] = $part;
}
print_r($vals);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [start_time] => start_time >= '2021-07-29 12:00'
    [end_time] => end_time <= '2021-07-30 12:00'
    [customer_id] => customer_id = '12'
    [wipe_status] => wipe_status = 'SUCCESS'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` to do this if you like.  An example would be:

```
$source = "start_time >= '2021-07-29 12:00' AND end_time <= '2021-07-30 12:00' AND customer_id = '12' AND wipe_status = 'SUCCESS'";

$output = array();
foreach (explode(" AND ", $source) as $value) {
  foreach (explode(" OR ", $value) as $value2) {
    $output[] = $value2;
  }
}

var_dump($output);
```

This will output:

```
array(4)
{
    [0]=> string(32) "start_time >= '2021-07-29 12:00'" 
    [1]=> string(30) "end_time <= '2021-07-30 12:00'" 
    [2]=> string(18) "customer_id = '12'" 
    [3]=> string(23) "wipe_status = 'SUCCESS'" 
}
```

This will work for `AND` or `OR` as requested.

Important note:  `explode` is case-sensitive.  If a non-uppercase `AND` or `OR` is used then this will not work.  The better choice if there is no guaranteed case is to use the regular expression method `preg_split` which has already been shown in an answer.